# Chrome and it's handling of %s

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

When using percentages (%) for the sizing of my elements, Chrome apparently prefers to make up its own rules mathematically.

It is my understanding that when you add 80 + 20, you get 100; right? Okay good. Chrome understands this too. But what if we write the same equation differently. For instance: (78 + 1 + 1) + (18 + 1 + 1) What'd you get? Was it 100? Yeah, me too.

So then can somebody **please** tell me why Chrome thinks otherwise?

Take two elements and float them alongside one another. Then, apply `width:20%` to one element and `width:80%` to the remaining element. You'll notice that 100% of the page (or container) has been occupied by both elements side-by-side. However, let's keep it simple and add a padding of only 1% to both sides of each element. This means one element will have `width:18%; padding:1%` and the other element will have `width:78%; padding:1%`. In theory, this should still have the same result: 100% of the page (or container) is occupied by both elements side-by-side. But in Chrome, this simply isn't so. It falls short.

The proof is in the pudding: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcA4F/1/) (you'll notice the slight differences if you're using Chrome).

It's frustrating because when it all adds up, especially with a higher volume of elements being used side-by-side, it can really throw a layout out of whack. I know that by creating child elements to take care of padding and/or the margins, we can avoid the situation, but this can lead to the use of markup that would otherwise be redundant.

I just need an explanation as to why Chrome behaves this way (maybe it's a Webkit thing altogether, I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: It looks like a rounding error. You'll notice if you slowly resize that it jumps around a bit. I suspect Chrome is rounding each of the 1% separately, so when the total width is say 240px, you'll end up with 4 lots of padding of 2px each, leaving a 4px gap at the end.

Comment: Yep, definitely a rounding "error".  Or rather, WebKit seems to understand that there's no such thing as a fractional pixel, and truncates to the nearest whole pixel if you do something that causes it to end up with a fractional pixel.  This is easily demonstrated by picking a fixed container width that splits evenly across all the percentages being used without generating any fractional components.  For instance:  http://jsfiddle.net/XcA4F/2/

Comment: Webkit works with [subpixel rendering](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/116009) since may 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [bug](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by changing chrome's webkit margin e.g. I used:

-webkit-margin-start: -5%;

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper around your floating elements, with overflow hidden (just in case). Then on the div that's not rounding properly, use calc(X% + 1px) to fix the issue.