# Why does 5% padding on the left and right of a 90% width div not give me 100% width?

Tags: css, html, percentage

I've had a strange issue with a header for a mobile site with the following code:

```
padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
width: 90%;
```

You can see the effect here -> http://cssdesk.com/vEMCY

The div with this code in is fractionally shorter than a div with no padding an a width of 100%.

I've got around it by putting margin's round the elements in the header and taking padding off and setting the width to 100% but I'm curious as to why it's done this as last I checked 5 + 5  + 90 = 100.

Comment: What browser are you using to see this? Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Chrome and Mobile Safari (both Webkit) so you might be onto something with the bug -> http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

Comment: That is precisely the problem, I assure you. Also, please disregard some of the posts below; padding measurements have nothing to do with the interior of the element. They correspond directly with the width just as margins do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit-based browsers have a rounding bug with percentage measurements.

A little while back, I had asked a very similar question and that seemed to be the issue. Refer to: [Chrome and it's handling of %s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9797874/1181243)

The post detailing the problem **[can be found here](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/)** (originally shared by **bookcasey**).

Comment: I've checked my example in Firefox and IE and it's fine. Interesting bug. That's the first time Chrome's been a problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how this is defined in CSS specs as I don't tend to use percentage padding, but is padding related to the containing element or itself?  If it is the element itself then it will be 5% of 90% ie 4.5%.  You'll lose 1% like that which is what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

solved out the css

```
 .header {
 background: blue;
 width: 90%;
 padding:10px 5.05% 10px 5.05%;

}
```

but couldn't find out where is this 0.1% padding is taking for the div#header...