# Weird math when using percentage based layout

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with two main divs.  The width of each div is 45%.  Yet when I inspect the divs at different page widths the the divs are usually one pixel different from each other.  639 vs 640.  I don't really care about this, the only problem is that items inside the smaller div aren't lining up properly with other items. It only happens at certain page widths but it is broken more than it is correct. It seems the elements in the larger div line up at any window size and the smaller div is almost always wrong, but is correct at some sizes.

What is going on here, is there a way to force the smaller div to act like the larger div?

Comment: Usually this is due to margins, padding, borders, or other bits of CSS styling (and browser-specific defaults) that causes such discrepancies. You should try using a CSS reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug/sub-pixel issue.

[I've asked a similar question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797874/chrome-and-its-handling-of-s) and found out that webkit-based browsers have a rounding issue when it comes to percentages.

**[Here's the link](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/) that bookcasey shared with me to answer my question.**

Comment: See also http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/. It's from 2008, but percentage widths have been problematic for a long time.

Comment: Great resources, is there an accepted fix? possibly only allowing certain dimensions that split up nicely?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a widely accepted way of addressing it just yet. Personally, through trial and error, I was able to design around it and try to give the impression that things weren't off.

Answer (score 4):

Widths must be in integer amounts.

What is 45% of 955? `429.75px`. Can't have that. So one of them has to be wider than the other.

Comment: but why does one convert 429.75 to 429 and the other to 430.  What is the solution to this.  Should I force my content div to be divisible by 2

Comment: Because that's the only way you can get 90% total. My example may not work exactly because 90% comes to something and a half so there's some guesswork going on there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use percentages, and if you do, make sure the total width adds to a bit below 100%. I've always run into overflow and misalignment issues when using 100%.

I'm assuming you have another div that takes up the remaining 10%. So, perhaps try 44% on both.

Comment: The overflow gets caused by margin, padding and in some browsers, border thickness.

Comment: I tried this but the divs are already smaller than the whole page and shrinking the percentage doesn't help.