# Do different browsers render decimal percentage sizes differently?

Tags: html, css

When setting widths of elements with CSS, I often end up wanting to set percentage widths that aren't whole percentages.

Do all (which I doubt) browsers handle decimal percentages in the same way, or do they render differently?

Can I accurately use it for layouts?

Comment: As far as whole percentages yet. But decimal percentages no. Some round up, others round down, and others will use the exact digit given

Comment: I would recommend you to do some tests...

Comment: Just guessing the results of the tests: IE do exact the opposite thing the other browsers do...

Comment: Well, I kind of know the short answer from a quick search, which is "Yes, they render differently". But which one does what, and how much. The resources supplied by Vinny is a nice start though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they do.

From my memory:

In Opera, you cannot set the decimal places of the percentage so, if you set 33.3% it uses only 33% (rather annoying) (edit:Opera may have improved on that in current version as it seems)

In Firefox, if you have percentages that add up to 100%, the pixels don't always add up to the 100% of the pixels
e.g. you have a outer div with three columns all with width: 33.33333%. If the outer div has width 100px, the columns will have 33 pixels and the sum is 99 pixels and not 100.
(edit: Firefox does better than I remember. Maybe they improved)

Old IE, I cannot remember IE9 seems to work fine. The bad one of course is IE7, which rounds up (as the IE6, but who cares?). IE8/9 seem to work ok

Chrome works fine

Safari: can't remember

---

### edit

Her one can test for oneself
http://jsfiddle.net/fTpFw/

---

### conclusion

After I played with my fiddle in different browsers I think they all have improved. The only bad implementations (from what I want to achieve) in modern browsers is Opera and Safari. IE7 is a stopper, too. If you don't have to deal with these buggers, you could go ahead and use the percentage widths.

Comment: Does it really round down to 33%, and not just flooring the calculated value? That's a whopping 3 pixels difference on a width of 1000px (If I'm not completely crap at calculating), if so, that's crazy...

Comment: As I wrote. It's from my memory. I don't have a example at hand, but that's what I remember.

Comment: As of Safari 7.0.2, seems it's still rounding down decimals when width is specified as percentage. For example, in Chrome and FF I get a correct width of 9.88px, whereas when I inspect in Safari, I just get 9px. Causes major headaches when creating precise grids, working with responsive layouts..

Answer (score 5):

Webkit browsers handle sub-pixel rounding very differently than other browsers. So much so that it's considered an ongoing issue. Meanwhile, Firefox and Opera seem to be able to handle sub-pixel rendering just fine; I haven't heard of many issues.

IE is another story entirely.

Here are some links for more about this topic:

- [Sub-Pixel Problems in CSS](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)
- [Percentage Bugs in Webkit](http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/)

[I asked a question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797874/chrome-and-its-handling-of-s) a little while back. This is what I've been able to gather since then (from both the accepted answer and elsewhere).

Comment: Maybe, the browsers have evolved a bit since these tests. Play with my fiddle in the browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/fTpFw/

Comment: Chrome still renders them short.